# partial derivative exercice

Tags: partial-derivative

Having $y=f(x,p)$ and $x=g(p,y) $ and considering we already know  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}; \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}; \frac{\partial g}{\partial p}; \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} $

Find $\frac{dy}{dx} $ using the 4 derivatives above

Comment: Are you sure about the functions because now you have $y=f(g(p,y),p) = f(g(p,f(x,p))) = ...$ that would never end I think.

Comment: @Leviathan, if we define $F, G : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ by $F(x,y,p) = f(x,p) - y$ and $G(x,y,p) = g(p,y) - x$, we have two equations, $F(x,y,p)=0$ and $G(x,y,p) = 0$, that each define a surface in $\mathbb R^3$. The intersection of these is a curve, and we want to know how $y$ changes along that curve when $x$ changes a little.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the equations, we have
$$dy = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} dp$$
$$dx = \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dp + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dy$$

Now we eliminate $dp$ by first multiplying the equations with $\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$ respectively:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dy = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dp$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} dx = \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dp + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dy$$
and then subtracting:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dy - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} dx
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} dx
- \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dy.$$

Collecting $dy$ on the left side and $dx$ on the right side, we get
$$\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right) dy
= \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} \right) dx$$

Thus,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} }{ \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} }$$

Comment: Thank you, straight to the point

Comment: Using differentials in this way might be a bit unrigorous, but it's just to think of them as derivatives w.r.t. some unnamed parameter.